# How to run tests which are located in same file as production code with pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I know this violates any [best practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) which require/assume proper packaging of Python production code: In some cases it might be helpful to beeing able to define production and test code in the same file (e.g. in case of simple scripts). How can I run all or specific tests in a file with `pytest` then?

**EDIT** - The solution for my particular use case:

file structure in `<root>`:

```
pytest.ini
scrip_with_tests.py
```

content of `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files = script_with_tests.py
```

content of `script_with_tests.py`:

```
import pytest  # this is not required, works without as well

def test_always_pass():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`pytest` invocation in `<root>`:

```
pytest script_with_tests.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [Customizing test collection](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection) section:

> You can easily instruct `pytest` to discover tests from every Python file:
>
> ```
> # content of pytest.ini
> [pytest]
> python_files = *.py
> ```
>
> However, many projects will have a `setup.py` which they don’t want to be imported. Moreover, there may files only importable by a specific python version. For such cases you can dynamically define files to be ignored by listing them in a `conftest.py` file:
>
> ```
> # content of conftest.py
> import sys
>
> collect_ignore = ["setup.py"]
> if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
>    collect_ignore.append("pkg/module_py2.py")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For very simple cases, placing the test inside the same file and then running `pytest main.py` should already be sufficient.

```py
# in main.py

def compute():
    return 42

def test_compute():
    assert compute() == 42

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compute())
```

```bash
pytest main.py # run all tests in file
pytest main.py::test_compute # or even select a specific test
python main.py # run script without tests
```